# SSIS 2012, clarify date conversion, how it works

Tags: sql-server, ssis

all
I have pretty simple pack to bring data from table to table (all MS SQL). However I'm stuck on something strange I have 2 sources and one destination table and it works for 1 and failing for 2.
Destination DDL:

```
DestTable (
MyDate  date,
...
```

Source 1.     Works OK directly in SSIS without any conversion  e.g. 20151025 -> date format

```
MyDateOK varchar(10)  -- 2015-10-25
in SSIS presented like: Unicode String [DT_WSTR]
```

Source 2.     Failing with truncation error.

```
MyDateFail datetime  ---2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
in SSIS presented like: DT_DBTIMESTAMP
```

I'm trying to fix this with Derived column transformation, but this all strange, + I can't use trim on DT_DBTIMESTAMP, what is the best way to handle this  flow?
Should datetime(aka dbtimestamp) be accepted by date without any fixes?
Best
Mario

Comment: What expression did you try in the derived column transform?

Answer (score 1):

Source 1 should be mapped into `DT_STR` in SSIS, otherwise you can get implicit ANSI to Unicode conversion which can get messy.

Source 2 should be explicitly converted to `DT_DBDATE` to get date part only.

Check this link: [Integration Services Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036(v=sql.110).aspx) in order to get a general understanding of database-to-SSIS data types mapping scheme. Also, the [Cast (SSIS Expression)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141704(v=sql.110).aspx) might be of some help.